# Could not get applicationId for .... Project type: PROJECT_TYPE_LIBRARY

Tags: android-studio

I am developing a library in AndroidStudio, that is used by several of my projects.

I am getting the following error all the time:

> Could not get applicationId for CommonLib.library.main. Project type: PROJECT_TYPE_LIBRARY
>
> java.lang.Throwable   at
> com.android.tools.idea.run.GradleApplicationIdProvider.getPackageName(GradleApplicationIdProvider.kt:111)
> at
> com.android.tools.idea.run.deployment.DeviceAndSnapshotComboBoxDeployableProvider.getPackageName(DeviceAndSnapshotComboBoxDeployableProvider.java:82)
> at
> com.android.tools.idea.run.deployment.DeviceAndSnapshotComboBoxDeployableProvider.getDeployable(DeviceAndSnapshotComboBoxDeployableProvider.java:75)
> at
> com.android.tools.idea.run.ui.BaseAction.getDisableMessage(BaseAction.java:169)
> ...

From the documentation I understood that is should not be needed, as a library never gets published on the Play Store anyway, but if I add it to the build.gradle like:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "CommonLib.library.main"
    }
```

the error is gone.

Problem now is I cannot build my projects anymore:

> Library projects cannot set applicationId. applicationId is set to 'CommonLib.library.main' in default config.

What is the correct way to handle applicationId on Library projects?

Answer (score 1):

Modify your project build.gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.library' version '8.0.0' apply false
}
```

And in your app build.gradle add this:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.library'
}
```

Libraries doesn't need applicationId. You must remove that.